# Error creating floating button on a Google map with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-button

I'm trying to create a floating button in android studio on a Google map. The objective of the button is to update marks on the map, but when trying to inflate it gives me the following error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kakao/com.example.kakao.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3297)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3405)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.kakao-OUJ-bqVa2zcpC7rS80Bifg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.kakao.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:76)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3250)
```

The button in xml:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/my_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_alert_circle_white_36dp" />
```

The reference and inflated in java:

```
   FloatingActionButton my_fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.my_fab);

    my_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Tocaste el FAB", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src`.

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_alert_circle_white_36dp"
```

The correct xml will be

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/my_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_alert_circle_white_36dp" />
```

Comment: I just added it, but it gives me the following error: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kakao/com.example.kakao.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Comment: Have you removed `android:src` ?

Comment: right he had Android: src = "@ drawable / ic_launch" per app: srcCompat = "@ drawable / ic_lauch". I get an error, it may be because I'm on a fragment.

Comment: Answer edited. You need to remove `android: src = "@ drawable / ic_launch"`.

Comment: It is the final code:

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android: id = "@ + id / my_fab"
        android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
        Android: layout_gravity = "bottom | end"
        Android: layout_margin = "16dp"
        app: srcCompat = "@ drawable / ic_launch" />

Comment: Because it is a necessary step that complements the solution

Comment: this wasn't the error in the question ! in you question the errors was : class not found ! and i gave the right answer to your question !

Answer (score 0):

you are working with **androidx** library so the class you should using for FAB in your xml is :

```
com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
```

instead of :

```
android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

Comment: correct when using androidX directly imports the first library. The other gives error.